# Angular error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'text'

Tags: angular, forms

I´m trying to write a unit test for editing a text inside a comment, but I am getting an error `Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'text'`  I want to expand on my unit test but I am already getting an error - can you suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="modal" id="edit-comment-modal">
  <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editComment()">
    <textarea
      id="edit-text"
      formControlName="text"
    ></textarea>
   <button type="submit"">Edit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
export class EditCommentComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() comment;
 editForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(
    private editService: editService,
  ) {}
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      text: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

 public editComment(): void {
    this.editService.editComment(this.editForm.value, this.comment.id)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.comment.text = this.editForm.value.text;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

```
 it('should edit comment', () => {
    component.editForm.value.text = 'Text comment';
    component.comment.text = component.editForm.value.text;
    expect(component.comment.text).toEqual(component.editForm.value.text);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are missing either `ReactiveFormsModule` or `FormsModule` imported in your test module

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...,
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Andrei. Unfortunatelly, this is not the case. I have both```import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';``` imported in my spec.ts file

Comment: I realized, that every test that was previously inside the same spec file where I´m creating test for edit comment is now with the same error, even the ```it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });```  Any idea why?